# python logistic regression - patsy design matrix and categorical data

Tags: python, scikit-learn, patsy

Quite new to python and machine learning.

I am trying to build a logistic regression model. I have worked in R to gain lambda and used cross-validation to find the best model and am now moving it into python.

Here I have created a design matrix and made it sparse. Then ran the logistic regression. It seems to be working.

My question is, since I have stated my term item_number is a category how to I know which has become the dummy variable? And how do I know which coefficient goes with each category name?

```
from patsy import dmatrices
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn import preprocessing


def train_model (data, frm, Rlambda):
    y, X = dmatrices(frm , data, return_type="matrix")
    y = np.ravel(y)

    scaler = sklearn.preprocessing.MaxAbsScaler(copy=False)
    X_trans = scaler.fit_transform(X)

    model = LogisticRegression(penalty ='l2', C=1/Rlambda)
    model = model.fit(X_trans, y)

frm = 'purchase ~ price + C(item_number)'
Rlambda = 0.01
model, train_score = train_model(data1,frm,Rlambda)
```

Answer (score 2):

First I will fix an error with your code and then I will answer your question.

Your code:
Your `train_model` function won't return what you think it returns. Currently, it doesn't return anything, and you want it to return both your model and the training score. When you fit a model, you need to define what you mean by the training score - the model won't return anything to you by default. For now let's just return the model that you trained.

So you should update your `train_model` function as follows:

```
def train_model (data, frm, Rlambda):
    y, X = dmatrices(frm , data, return_type="matrix")
    y = np.ravel(y)

    scaler = sklearn.preprocessing.MaxAbsScaler(copy=False)
    X_trans = scaler.fit_transform(X)

    model = LogisticRegression(penalty ='l2', C=1/Rlambda)

    # model.fit() operates in-place
    model.fit(X_trans, y)

    return model
```

Now when you want to determine what variables correspond to, `model.coef_` returns you all the coefficients in the decision function, of size `(n_classes, n_features)`. The order of the coefficients correspond to the order that your features were passed into the `.fit()` method. So in your case, `X_trans` is the design matrix of size `(n_samples, n_features)`, so each of the coefficients in `model.coef_` exactly correspond to the coefficients for each of the `n_features` in `X` in the same order they are presented in `X`.

Comment: Thanks for the debug. Ok so they are coming out the same as they went in. But since I am passing in categorical data shouldn't one of the categories become the dummy variable and then disappear?

Comment: Suppose `item_number` takes values from 1 to 5, then after `C(item_number)`, you  get 4 dummies (takes 0, 1). If you really care about the matching between coefficients and dummies names, you really need to label your dataset first, you may return dataframe rather than matrix, set `return_type='dataframe'` instead. And use x.head(), x.columns, etc. to look up variable names.